# Do I need a comma in "in today's case" in the following sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> I visited my school's dwarf garden whenever I felt down (or fell down **[,] in today's case**). Eyes closed, I would touch my nose to the flowers and let their musky fragrance wash away my murky thoughts.

Do I need that comma there? Why or why not?

Comment: Such a comma isn't really a "syntactic" element - it's just a matter of reflecting an optional *pause* if you imagine speaking the words. If you would use that pause in speech, include a comma. If not, don't. Just be aware that *some* people might find it easier to parse the text with the comma present. But if you were bothered about that you could always write ***fell*** in italics (or speak the word with heavy stress), in which case they wouldn't need that extra clue to assist parsing (but it would still  be your stylistic choice whether to include it).

Comment: @Fumble - MYTH: You should add a comma [wherever you pause](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/commas/). Where you pause or breathe in a sentence does not reliably indicate where a comma belongs. The biggest confusion regarding commas stems from a terrible urban legend: “If you want to know where a comma goes, just put it [wherever you want a pause](http://thewritepractice.com/commas/).”  In fact, one of the biggest mistakes people make is to simply place a comma [wherever they want the reader to pause](https://www.writingforward.com/grammar/punctuation-marks/punctuation-marks-the-comma).

Comment: @J.R.: We're dealing with an area where there's no real consensus (plus there's a long-term trend continually *reducing* the use of such punctuation marks). But the bottom line is orthography is just a crude attempt to reflect real (spoken) language, and in any context where a comma *doesn't* reflect a spoken pause, increasing numbers of writers won't include it, regardless of what traditionalists might think. In short, what you've written isn't MYTH - it's MYOPINION. I mean *your* opinion, since I obviously disagree - particularly as regards ***useful*** advice for non-native speakers.

Comment: @Fumble - Just to be clear, the word "myth" in all caps was in the original (as was the entirety of my comment, which was merely pasted from three websites). I agree there is little consensus – which was the whole point of my comment, to show counterarguments to what you stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean "I visited my school's small garden because I felt down."?
"in today's case" is not especially necessary.
If I were you, for example, I'd say:
*I visited my school's small garden because I felt down. I was sad today.*

"Whenever" means every time. If you use it,
*I visit my school's small garden whenever I feel down.*

*Eyes closed, I would touch my nose to the flowers and let their musky fragrance wash away my murky thoughts.*

"Closing eyes,". This is called "Dangling modifier". It needs a comma like you did.